# sending 2 requests via socket

Tags: php, sockets, tcp

i am trying to send 2 responces to same connection. but i am having problem sending. some times 2nd request missing .

can anybody help how to make sure 2nd request is going correctly on same connection.

for some reason my clent accept two requests. 
1. count of message.
2. message to show.

```
$valCount = str_pad(strlen($message), 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
socket_write($socket, $valCount) or die("[" . @date('H:i:s') ."] Could not send output\n");
socket_write($socket, $message) or die("[" . @date('H:i:s') ."] Could not send output\n");
```

Comment: It's quite possible that your socket writes are being done fine and the problem is on the receiving code. But without any proper attempt at debugging it's just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

I have observed that when you are programming sockets on a local machine ( both client and server are on the same machine ) this happens.

My code had two responses sent from server to the client and what happened was that the first response was buffered ( not actually sent) and when the second request arrived , it was all sent together to the client.

So your string might have two responses appended together.
If this is the case then you don't need to worry because this won't happen when the server and the client are on different machines.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `socket_write()` does not guarantee that all the data passed to it is sent. From the [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-write.php):

> `socket_write()` does not necessarily write all bytes from the given buffer. It's valid that, depending on the network buffers etc., only a certain amount of data, even one byte, is written though your buffer is greater. You have to watch out so you don't unintentionally forget to transmit the rest of your data.

The function will return an integer that describes the number of bytes that were successfully sent. You need to check the return value to ensure that you correctly send all the data.

Something like this:

```
// An array of the messages to send
$messagesToSend = array();
$messagesToSend[] = str_pad(strlen($message), 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
$messagesToSend[] = $message;

// Loop the message queue
foreach ($messagesToSend as $data) {

  // Loop while still data to send
  while ($data) {

    // Send data
    $bytesSent = socket_write($socket, $data);

    // Check for failures
    if ($bytesSent === FALSE) {
      die("[".date('H:i:s')."] Could not send output (".socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)).")\n");
    }

    // Trim the data that was sent off $data
    // This approach means that the while() loop will finish when all the data
    // has been sent - $data will be an empty string so will evaluate to FALSE
    $data = substr($data, $bytesSent);

  } // while

} // foreach
```